# Popper and indeterminism, why is it part of philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, popper

Popper states that:

> ...There can be 2 incompatible theory, equally irrefutable; for example, determinism and his opposite, indeterminism.

Popper; Conjecture and Confutation chapter 8.

How can determinism not be a scientific theory, if we can clearly confutate it? For Popper determinism is:

> "Future is conteined in the present, because is from it complitelly determined."

This theory is clearly confutable, since we just need one experiment that proves that in *just one* case something *is not determined*.
Why he calls it a non-scientific theory?

Comment: There is no "just one case" with determinism, the universe does not split into causally isolated cases. Nor can we tell if a prediction of determinism came true or not. To prove that the future is not determined by the present we would have to first gather all the data about the present from all over the universe. Even then we can not be sure that we did not miss some law of nature that determines it even if we can't, or that our own actions aren't predetermined. And both our data and our measurements aren't infinitely precise, so that there is always a chance that we messed up.

Comment: @Conifold What I'm asking is whether It is a scientific theory or not. Determinism means "everything is determined", so to confutate it you need 1 case in which 1 event was not determined by something, but was completely casual. From a logical point of view this theory can be falisified as much as the theory "every single man is taller that a mountain", and it's equally scientific. Moreover, what i got from Popper, i might be wrong, is that what he means by refutable is "logically refutable"; you need to controll an infinite number of cases to demonstrate something, but u need onli one to

Comment: @Conifold refutate he theory. The problem of stumentation never came to my attention for now in Popper's books, but i think that if something is not refutable because of the lack of precision in the instruments or of our current knowledge, then nothing at all can be refutate, so even einstein theories are not scientific, because we are not able to surelly refutate them due to the imprecision of our instruments...

Comment: No, determinism is not a scientific theory, it is a metaphysical doctrine. But there can be scientific theories that are deterministic, classical mechanics was one, so it can be used as a guideline for developing new theories. The difference is that classical mechanics made specific predictions about specific outcomes, whereas determinism in general is so vague that it can be made compatible with *any* outcome. It is true that just one negative outcome can falsify a theory, but there is no possible way to get one with determinism. "Everything is determined" predicts nothing in particular

Comment: @Conifold Well we could say that it predicts a lot. It predicts that if u have an event A, that event had surelly a cause B. And this is true for every singol event in the universe. Probably the point is that you cannot experiment  the quality of determination, and surelly u cannot know for sure that it was not determined by something u don't know.

Comment: I am afraid, it predicts nothing. Single events cause nothing by themselves, the entire environment, the whole universe, theoretically, contributes to the causing. Throwing a rock only "causes" the window to break if the gust of wind does not blow it off course, etc. The archaic event-to-event concept of causation is rejected in modern physics, we have global initial conditions and evolution laws instead. And if it takes omniscient God to falsify determinism, it is unfalsifiable.

Comment: @Conifold Of course there is no 1 to 1 event, but still, if the rock breaks the window, the rock was at least 1 cause, but not the only. In the same way, determinism predicts that every single event in the univers has at least 1 cause. If we could demonstrate that an event X has no cause, zero, determinism would be confutated. The point os that ot's impossible to state that nothing coused X, because it requires you to know everything. But still, determinism predicts something.

Comment: Except *we* can not demonstrate anything of the sort, for the same reason, only God can. *We* can only say that *we* did not find a cause yet (as some people say about quantum outcomes, for example). Falsifiable in science means falsifiable *for us*. And, *for us*, determinism predicts nothing, which is the only prediction that matters. As Peirce put it, it is easy to be never wrong, one just has to be sufficiently vague. A falsifiable deterministic *theory* must be far more specific than the metaphysical doctrine of determinism.

Comment: @Conifold I agree with you, but probably I have a different idea of prediction. Prediction is not, I think, connected with whether or not it is falsifiable. If i say "one day, somewhere, someone will say exactly what i'm saying now", this is a prediction, even if it is not falsifiable. It's not a scientific because it's not falsifiable nor demonstrable, but still it's a prediction, in the sense that tries to predict some events of the future.

Comment: Your prediction is at least verifiable, we can see it happen, determinism is too vague for that as well. But I am not sure how useful is the notion of prediction that only God can make use of, he already knows everything anyway.

Comment: @Conifold That's actually a good point i must say. I'm just a bit maniac and wanted to clarify what a prediction is. I think that even sayin "tomorrow, in the spirit real, an actual frog will save our world from a giant phantom" is a prediction. Of course it's averithing but scientific, nor it's founded on some rational reason, bit i still call it prediction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot know in any given experiment that something was not determined, only that it was not determined by the set of rules proposed.

So to run your experiment you would need a perfect set of rules.

This set of predictive rules would correctly predict all outcomes that can be predicted.

But then the set of rules already decided whether there is or is not determinism.

Say it decides there is determinism.

Then the test case cannot defy the rules, or they have failed to be perfect.

So the rules should decide against determinism.

Then there is no point in running the experiment.

A test case is not a confutation if it agrees with the predicted outcome.

Comment: Nice explanation! Though I prefer the shorter pithier version before the last edit

Comment: I thought about something like this after i wrote the question, tell me if it is correct. We cannot know if that event didn't seem determined because it was not determined or because it was determined by something that we don't know.